# Inner product with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

I am learning linear algebra, I was told that we can use the infinite set ${1, x, x^2, x^3, ...}$ to span the polynomial space, and to approximate an arbitrary real function. Is there an inner product that makes this set an orthonormal set? And with this inner product, how can I approximate a real function by projecting onto the space spanned by this set?

Comment: It's not true that $\overline{Span\{1,x,x^2,...\}}=\mathcal F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$...

Comment: You can define $\left(\sum_0^na_ix^i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_0^nb_ix^i\right)=\sum_0^na_ib_i$. But you may have misunderstood what you were told about approximating "an arbitrary real function." Real functions can be very hairy.

Comment: The questions are linked, because the way you measure how close two polynomials are to each other depends on what the inner product is.  Typically, the inner product is given by the integral of the product of the polynomials on a finite domain, such as $[0,1]$, so closeness is measured on that domain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: Thank you for your helpful replies. The idea of an infinite dimension vector space is still blurry to me. My question arises when I was introduced the orthonormal Fourier basis for the space of square-integrable functions on $[0,1]$ (with the inner product that @Paul mentioned), I was curious about the equivalent inner product if we change from the set of trigonometric functions to the set of monomials. Sorry if I understand these things wrong.